# PHP ODBC HANA Feature (SCROLLABLE RESULT) not implemented

Tags: php, odbc, hana

1. I've confirmed that this script connects:

   ```
   $db_name = "hana";
   $username = "SYSTEM";
   $password = "my_real_password";

   $conn = odbc_connect($db_name, $username, $password) or die(odbc_error_msg()); 
   $sql = "SELECT REGION_NAME, SUM(SALES_AMOUNT) FROM \"_SYS_BIC\".\"mydemo/CV_SALES\" GROUP BY REGION_NAME"; 
   $result = odbc_prepare($conn, $sql);

   odbc_close($conn);
   ```
2. When I run $result = odbc_prepare($conn, $sql); it throws me this error

   > PHP Warning:  odbc_prepare(): SQL error: [unixODBC][SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB SO][HDB] General error;-10808 Feature (SCROLLABLE RESULT) not implemented yet in module: /HDB/IMP/NewDB100_REL/src///sys/src/Inter, SQL state S1000 in SQLPrepare in /home/payomdousti/Developer/hana.php on line 9

   I used this to install the php odbc driver => sudo apt-get install php5-odbc

   **PHP Version**

   ```
   PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Sep 12 2012 18:59:41) 
   Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
   Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
   ```

   I'm using unixODBC as you can see with the HDB driver from Rev38 SAP HANA.
3. I'm able to prepare and execute the query successfully in Python using pyodbc with the following code.

   ```
    import pyodbc
    conn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=hana;UID=SYSTEM;PWD=my_real_password')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT REGION_NAME, SUM(SALES_AMOUNT) FROM \"_SYS_BIC\".\"mydemo/CV_SALES\" GROUP BY REGION_NAME")
    print cursor.fetchall()
    conn.close()
   ```

It's a business requirement to connect via PHP over ODBC. We don't have access to SAP XS so this is really the best option. I'm not interested in solutions using RFC, SOAP, OData or XMLA

Answer (score 0):

According to your error, it looks like the SAP HDB driver you're using doesn't support scrollable cursors. Have you tried creating a non-scrollable (forward only) cursor?

For instance, in Microsoft SQL Server, you would have to set `SQL_ATTR_CURSOR_TYPE` to `SQL_CURSOR_FORWARD_ONLY`.